# Display Filtered Data in Angular Table Based on Dropdown Selections

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular application that involves displaying data in a table. The data is fetched from the server and includes various properties such as opisAkcije, ukupanIznos, ukupanBrojZahtjeva, etc.

I have implemented two dropdowns for filtering the data in the table:

Vrsta Proizvoda (Product Type): The user can select a specific product type from this dropdown.
Tip Komitenta (Customer Type): The user can select a specific customer type from this dropdown.

I have also implemented two charts (a pie chart and a bar chart) that represent the data fetched from the server. When the user clicks on a segment in either chart, I update the data displayed in the table to show the filtered results based on the selected segment.

However, there seems to be an issue with updating the table data correctly. When I select a value from the dropdowns, the data in the table does not update accordingly. It's displaying the entire dataset when page load and when I choose some value from dropdown there is nothing instead of the filtered data.

```
 vrstaProizvodaOptions: string[] = Object.keys(VrstaProizvoda).filter(
    (key) => isNaN(Number(VrstaProizvoda[key]))
  );
  
  tipKomitentaOptions: string[] = Object.keys(TipKomitenta).filter(
    (key) => isNaN(Number(TipKomitenta[key]))
  );
  organizacioneJediniceOptions: string[] = Object.keys(OrgJedTip).filter(
    (key) => isNaN(Number(OrgJedTip[key])) 
  )
  analiticariOptions: string[] = [];

  selectedVrstaProizvoda: string | null = null;
  selectedTipKomitenta: string | null = null;
  selectedOrganizacionaJedinica: string | null = null;
  selectedAnaliticar: string | null = null;
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();
    this.populateDropdowns();
    
  }
```

```
 updateFilteredData(): void {
    this.selectedZahtjevi = this.sviZahtjevi.filter((item) => {
      return (
        (!this.selectedVrstaProizvoda ||
          item.proizvodOpis === VrstaProizvoda[this.selectedVrstaProizvoda]) &&
        (!this.selectedTipKomitenta ||
          item.tipKomitenta === TipKomitenta[this.selectedTipKomitenta]) &&
        (!this.selectedTipKomitenta ||
          item.tipKomitenta === OrgJedTip[this.selectedTipKomitenta]) &&
        (!this.selectedAnaliticar || item.analiticar === this.selectedAnaliticar)
      );
    });
    this.updateChart();
  }
```

```
  updateChart() {
    const pieChart = new Chart(this.pieChartCanvasRef.nativeElement, {
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: this.pieChartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Suma finansiranja",
            data: this.pieChartData,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgb(255, 99, 132)", // Red
              "rgb(54, 162, 235)", // Blue
              "rgb(255, 205, 86)", // Yellow
              "rgb(75, 192, 192)", // Teal
              "rgb(153, 102, 255)", // Purple
              "rgb(255, 159, 64)", // Orange
              "rgb(128, 128, 128)", // Gray
              "rgb(180,220,120)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {},
        events: ["click"],
        onClick: this.chartClick.bind(this),
      },
    });

    const barChart = new Chart(this.barChartCanvasRef.nativeElement, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: this.barChartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Broj zahtjeva",
            data: this.barChartData,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgb(255, 99, 132)", // Red
              "rgb(54, 162, 235)", // Blue
              "rgb(255, 205, 86)", // Yellow
              "rgb(75, 192, 192)", // Teal
              "rgb(153, 102, 255)", // Purple
              "rgb(255, 159, 64)", // Orange
              "rgb(128, 128, 128)", // Gray
              "rgb(180,220,120)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
        onClick: this.chartClick.bind(this), // Add the onClick callback
      },
    });
  }
populateDropdowns(): void {
    this.vrstaProizvodaOptions = Object.keys(VrstaProizvoda)
      .filter((key) => isNaN(Number(VrstaProizvoda[key])))
      .map((key) => VrstaProizvoda[key]);

    this.tipKomitentaOptions = Object.keys(TipKomitenta)
      .filter((key) => isNaN(Number(TipKomitenta[key])))
      .map((key) => TipKomitenta[key]);

    this.organizacioneJediniceOptions = Object.keys(OrgJedTip)
      .filter((key) => isNaN(Number(OrgJedTip[key])))
      .map((key) => OrgJedTip[key]);
    console.log("operateri", OrgJedTip);

    this.analiticariOptions = Object.keys(UcitajSveOperatere)
      .filter((key) => isNaN(Number(UcitajSveOperatere[key])))
      .map((key) => UcitajSveOperatere[key]);
  }

  onDropdownChange(): void {
    this.updateFilteredData();
  }
```

```
  chartClick(event: MouseEvent, chart: Chart) {
    this.selectedPieChartValue = {
      label: this.pieChartLabels[chart[0].opisAkcije],
      value: this.pieChartData[chart[0].index],
    };
    this.selectedZahtjevi = this.sviZahtjevi.filter(
      (item) => item.opisAkcije == this.pieChartLabels[chart[0].index]
    );
    this.selectedBarChartValue = {
      label: this.barChartLabels[chart[0].index],
      value: this.barChartData[chart[0].index],
    };
  }
}
```

I expect to display filtered data in table based on dropdown value clicked